# How can I instantly kill a Perl thread without killing the entire program?

Tags: multithreading, perl

When I use `exit` or `die`, it kills the entire program.

```
foreach my $t (threads->list())
{
    $t->exit;
    $count++;
}

Usage: threads->exit(status) at main.pl line 265
Perl exited with active threads:
        9 running and unjoined
        0 finished and unjoined
        0 running and detached
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708864/how-do-i-kill-perl-threads/27690901#27690901

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To ignore a thread that is being executed, return back control and throw away whatever it may output, the right method to use is `detach`, not `exit`.

See [`perldoc perlthrtut` - Ignoring a Thread](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Ignoring-A-Thread).

---

[`perldoc threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) explains why the code exits:

> ```
> threads->exit()
> ```
>
> If needed, a thread can be exited at any time by calling
>   `threads->exit()`. This will cause the thread to return undef in a
>   scalar context, or the empty list in a list context. When called from
>   the *main* thread, this behaves the same as `exit(0)`.

---

There may be a way to achieve [instant termination](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#EXITING-A-THREAD) (didn't work for me on Windows):

> ```
> use threads 'exit' => 'threads_only';
> ```
>
> This globally overrides the default behavior of calling `exit()`
>   inside a thread, and effectively causes such calls to behave the same
>   as `threads->exit()` . In other words, with this setting, calling
>   `exit()` causes only the thread to terminate. Because of its global
>   effect, this setting should not be used inside modules or the like.
>   The main thread is unaffected by this setting.

The documentation also suggests another way, using the `set_thread_exit_only` method (Again, didn't work for me on Windows):

> ```
> $thr->set_thread_exit_only(boolean)
> ```
>
> This can be used to change the exit thread only behavior for a thread
>   after it has been created. With a true argument, `exit()` will cause
>   only the thread to exit. With a false argument, `exit()` will
>   terminate the application. The main thread is unaffected by this call.

---

The example below makes use of a kill [signal to terminate](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#THREAD-SIGNALLING) the `$unwanted` thread:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

my $unwanted = threads->create( sub {
                                      local $SIG{KILL} = sub { threads->exit };
                                      sleep 5;
                                      print "Don't print me!\n";
                                    } );

my $valid    = threads->create( sub {
                                      sleep 2;
                                      print "This will print!\n";
                                    } );

$unwanted->kill('KILL')->detach;   # Kills $thr, cleans up

$valid->join;                 # sleep 2, 'This will print!'
```

Comment: Is it not possible to just kill the thread entirely? Make it go bye bye, stop using up my CPU and RAM?

Comment: Yes, via `detach`.  Once the thread finishes, Perl will do the necessary cleanup.

Comment: I want to stop the thread in an instant. Should I just do this using an external method (a global boolean to tell when to stop)? I think that may work.

Comment: @Saustin : You can try `use threads 'exit' => 'threads_only';`, as updated in my answer.

Comment: It still does the same thing -- I tried both. I may just go ahead and use a global boolean.

Comment: @Saustin : I got it to work with thread signalling... updating my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to kill a thread, you kill it with `$thread->kill`. If you want to disown a thread but leave it running, use `$thread->detach`. `threads->exit` causes the *current* thread to exit; it doesn't take a thread as invocant.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that `$t->exit` requires an argument.  Try giving it one.  (`perldoc Threads` seems to say that it doesn't, but I don't know what package you're using.)

Comment: I'm using Threads. I have tried that; no game. I also did it with die.

Comment: Is `$t` a Threads object?  Try printing `ref $t`.  Is the expression in the `foreach` loop really `threads->list()`, or is it `Threads->list()`?

Comment: That is definitely not the problem.