# How do I kill Perl threads?

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

In this program I create a fork, and then call domultithreading from it. It then creates a few threads.

```
sub domultithreading {
    #Not my function
    my ($num) = @_;
    my @thrs;
    my $i = 0;
    my $connectionsperthread = 50;
    while ( $i < $num ) {
        $thrs[$i] = threads->create( \&doconnections, $connectionsperthread, 1 );
        $i += $connectionsperthread;
    }
    my @threadslist = threads->list();
    while ( $#threadslist > 0 ) {
        $failed = 0;
    }
}

sub kill {
    #how can I kill the threads made in domultithreading?
    kill 9, $pid;
    print "\nkilling $pid\n";
}
```

I then want to be able to kill the fork and its threads, however I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: All threads belong to the same process; killing `$pid` will implicitly kill all the threads. Are you trying some kind of "graceful shutdown"?

Comment: @creaktive Well when I kill $pid, the threads are still running; when i then close the program I get: "Perl exited with active threads: 10 running and unjoined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl provides two concurrency models: Processes and Threads. While you shouldn't neccessarily mix these two without a good reason, threads do model processes quite closely, so we can nearly treat them as such. Specifically, we can send signals to threads.

Processes can be signalled with the `kill` *function*: `kill SIGNAL => $pid`, while threads can be signalled with the `kill` *method*: `$thr->kill(SIGNAL)`. This method returns the thread object. Signals can be intercepted when setting signal handlers in the `%SIG` hash.

This means that every process `TERM` signal handler `TERM`s all the child threads like

```
 $_->kill(9)->join() for threads->list;
```

and every thread `TERM` signal handler simply exits the thread, or does cleaning up:

```
 threads->exit; # exit the current thread
```

Comment: I nearly understand this, $thr->kill(SIGNAL), should I have a loop through the thread list to kill(TERM) each one?

Comment: @OwenGarland Yes, however using barewords as signals won't work. See my first code example for the loop. `$_` denotes each thread object successively. You can look at the `kill` method in the [`threads` documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jdhedden/threads-1.86/lib/threads.pm#THREAD_SIGNALLING) for more information. Further information is available at the [`%SIG` docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25SIG), [`perldoc -f kill`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) and [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals).

Answer (score 2):

There are actually few different ways to kill a [thread](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.6/ext/threads/threads.pm) in Perl, depending on what you want to achieve.

Let's take the following code as example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

# Create the shared queue (used by the threads):
my $queue = Thread::Queue->new();

sub main {    
    # Initialise the shared queue:
    $queue->enqueue("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
    print "Total number of items: " . $queue->pending() . "\n";
    $queue->end();  # signal that there is no more work to be sent...

    # Create 3 threads:  
    threads->create('do') for ( 0..2 );
    print "Number of current threads: " . threads->list() . "\n";

    foreach my $thread ( threads->list() ) {  # for each thread...
        $thread->join();  # wait the thread to finish all its work...

        print "Number of items in the queue: " . $queue->pending() . "\n" if defined $queue->pending();
        print "Number of current threads: " . threads->list() . "\n";
    }
}

sub do {
    # Retrieve the current thread ID:
    my $threadID = threads->self()->tid();

    # Setup the thread's kill signal handler:
    local $SIG{KILL} = sub { threads->exit() };

    while ( defined (my $item = $queue->dequeue()) ) {  # for each element in the queue...
        print "(Thread-" . $threadID . "): Do something with item '$item'...\n";
        sleep 1 + $threadID;
        print "(Thread-" . $threadID . "): Finished to use item '$item'...\n";
    }
}


main();
```

The code above spawns 3 threads, each of which will take and process an element of the shared queue till the queue is empty.

In this case, since we declared that no more element will be added to the queue (i.e. *$queue->end()*), the threads will be joined (to the main) once they had processed all the elements of the queue. Indeed, using *$thread->join()* we are saying to the main to wait for *$thread* to join.

If we omit to declare *$queue->end()*, the threads will not join the main but stay pending for new elements of the queue.

Now, if we want to kill the threads, we have two options: killing the threads but letting them to finish what they are doing first or simply (brutally) killing the threads immediately. In Perl, both are achieved via [Thread Signalling](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html#THREAD-SIGNALLING).

In the first case (i.e. if we want to tell the threads to finish their work and, after, to stop processing the shared queue), we should use *$thread->kill('KILL')->join()*:

```
foreach my $thread ( threads->list() ) {  # for each thread...
    $thread->kill('KILL')->join();  # wait the thread finish its work and kill it...

    print "Number of items in the queue: " . $queue->pending() . "\n" if defined $queue->pending();
    print "Number of current threads: " . threads->list() . "\n";
}
```

On the other hand, in the latter case (i.e. if we want to kill the threads immediately), we should use *$thread->kill('KILL')->kill()*:

```
foreach my $thread ( threads->list() ) {  # for each thread...
    $thread->kill('KILL')->kill();  # kill the thread immediately...

    print "Number of items in the queue: " . $queue->pending() . "\n" if defined $queue->pending();
    print "Number of current threads: " . threads->list() . "\n";
}
```

Of course, if you want to kill the thread from within itself, you just need to call *threads->exit()* or simply use *[return](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html)*:

```
sub do {
    ...
    threads->exit();  # kill the thread...
    ...
}
```